# Angular "Can't bind to 'routerLink'" error on button element

Tags: html, angular, laravel, angular-directive, angular-router

I am working with an Angular project. I have the following routerLink in my employee.component.html file

```
 <td>
   <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm mx-2" routerLink="employee/{{emp.id}}">View Data</button>
</td>
```

and my Route in app.module.ts is

```
 {path: 'employee/:id', component:EmployeeByIdComponent}
```

I got the following error message in the visulecode IDE and not redirect to page
`Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.ngtsc(-998002) employees.component.ts(8, 21): Error occurs in the template of component EmployeesComponent.`

How can I make the button in employee.component.html route me to the EmployeeByIdComponent?

**Edit**
employee.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/service/data.service';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-employees',
  templateUrl: './employees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employees.component.css']
})



export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {
  employee:any;

  constructor(private dataService:DataService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEmployeesData();
  }

  getEmployeesData() {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(res => {
      this.employee = res;
    });
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck with this exactly? In HTML you create links with `<a href="`... etc. Are you asking how to create a link in general, or how to create a link with a valid route, or how to put the right ID into the link, or what? It's unclear. Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: @ADyson yes I need create href link and route to specific id employee

Comment: Ok. So what is the issue you're facing _exactly_, then? "I need" isn't a problem statement. What prevents you from just creating such a link? What have you tried so far? What went wrong with that attempt? See also [ask]

Comment: @ADyson yes I need how to write router link on Angular. I am not professional with Angular

Comment: You don't need to be professional, just read some documentation, look at examples, and have a go at it. **have you tried anything**? As volunteers we don't mind helping people, if they've demonstrably tried to help themselves first. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) . You learn a lot more by trying, than just asking others to do all the thinking for you.

Comment: I'm not a Laravel or Angular expert, but I'd guess you probably would just have to write something like `<td><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employee/{{emp.emp_no}}">{{emp.first_name}}</a></td>` . Ideally you'd ask Laravel to generate the URL for you so it's always right, but you seem to be in an Angular-only file rather than a Laravel Blade file, unless I'm wrong. That might only return the JSON of the employee though onto the page. Maybe you need to actually route the link to an _Angular_ route which points to the component where you display the employee, and pass in the emp_no

Comment: @amaruwakoi, I suggest you make a tour of heroes. Expecificaly in [this part](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt5#navigating-to-hero-details) explain how define a path with a route: `{ path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },` and how use `<a routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}">` and how get the parameter "id" in your component "detail"

Comment: @ADyson, **not** In Angular you don't use href unless you want to open a new page in a new app (this re-charge all the app), you use [routerLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)

Comment: @Eliseo thanks, as I said I'm not too familiar with it. Was just trying to prompt the OP to get their brain in gear at least :-)

Comment: @ADyson, a typical "master-Detail" in Angular can use router. This force a main.component with a `<router-outlet>`, a master.component (the list of the elements) and a detail.component. The another way is make a monolitic component. In the tutorial of tour of heroes you have both options (at first the "monolitic" component). I know it's takes some time, but it's enougth to "start coding"

Comment: Can you add your module typescript file? I suspect this issue stems from a missing dependency provider.

Answer (score 0):

You must import the [RouterLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) directive in order to use it.

Try adding the following line to your `employee.component.ts` file:

```
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
```

**Edit:**

I think it would align better with best practices if you import the `RouterModule` in your module file instead of importing RouterLink in your component file. Try adding `RouterModule` to the list of imports in your `app.module.ts` file.

Comment: same error plese see my employee.component.ts file